# How to plot a graph that creates vertical lines with labels that change based on input parameters

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am witting a program that plots spectral data and i need to know the given Redshift, what i am attempting to do is place vertical lines where the elements should be with labels to know which one it is on the graph. however i am unable to find an effective way to plot these lines but also their corresponding labels. I am using two lists, one for the xvals and the other for the labels from items in a csv file.

some of the issues i am having is not knowing how to effectively pass through values from a csv file to a tuple and then use that tuple list to plot x values and then display its corresponding label. this has to be flexible enough to change.

```
emission_line_list_string=[]
emission_line_elements=[]
emission_line_list=[] 
absorption_line_list_string=[]
absorption_line_elements=[]
absorption_line_list=[]
redshifted_em_lines=[]
redshifted_ab_lines=[]
em_list=[]
ab_list=[]
#=====================================================================
# default functions:

def emmission_lines(z_obs):
    redshift_formula=(1+z_obs)
    for i in emission_line_list:
        redshifted_em_lines.append(i)
    
def absorption_lines(z_obs):
    redshift_formula=(1+z_obs)
    for i in absorption_line_list:
        redshifted_ab_lines.append(i)
def merge_lists(list1,list2,merged_list):
    merged_list=tuple(zip(list1,list2))
    return merged_list

def graph_template(string):
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20, 60), dpi=80)
wavelength1, flux1= np.loadtxt(string,unpack=True)
ax = plt.subplot(10,1,1)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(6000,11000,200))
plt.xlim(5000,11000)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
plt.ylabel('Flux (10$^{-15}$ ergs cm$^{-2}$ s$^{-1}$ A$^{-1}$)',fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('wavelength ($\AA$)',fontsize=15)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='major',size=7,width=2,direction='in',top='on')
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(which='major',size=7,width=2,direction='in',right='on')
Smoothing = savgol_filter(flux1, 17, 4)
plt.plot(wavelength1, Smoothing)
```

this whole mess is my attempt at reading values from a csv file put those values in a list so i can use them to alter them based on redshift and plot them as well as storing the names

```
with open('emissionlines.csv',mode='r') as f:
reader=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=',')
for n, row in enumerate(reader):
    emission_line_list_string.append(row['wavelength'])
    emission_line_elements.append(row['element'])
f.close()
with open('absorptionlines.csv',mode='r') as f:
    reader=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=',')
    for n, row in enumerate(reader):
        absorption_line_list_string.append(row['wavelength'])
        absorption_line_elements.append(row['element'])
    f.close()
for i in emission_line_list_string:
    emission_line_list.append(float(i))
for i in absorption_line_list_string:
    absorption_line_list.append(float(i))
merge_lists(emission_line_list,emission_line_elements,em_list)
merge_lists(absorption_line_list,absorption_line_elements,em_list)
```

here is where i call upon all the functions

```
plt.title("Slit17, redshift=[]", fontsize=15)
z_obs = 1.2
emmission_lines(z)
absorption_lines(z)
graph_template('slit17.dat')
```

Comment: Maybe plt.stem is of interest?

Answer (score 0):

Nice effort, I can see you've been working hard on this. I'm struggling a little bit to understand what you're looking for but some of this may help. It would be helpful if you could show what your CSV file looks like (maybe a screenshot of excel) and some rough sketch (even an image of a piece of paper) of what you want the graph to look like. Here are some general suggestions and a solution that I think may be close to what you're trying to do.

You should use [Pandas](https://datatofish.com/import-csv-file-python-using-pandas/) to import your CSV and make a dataframe. This is a much easier and more convenient way of storing, manipulating, and plotting the data.

I did some Googling, and maybe you are looking for something like [this](http://astro.physics.uiowa.edu/ITU/labs/professional-labs/astronomical-redshift/advanced-instruments.html)? Here is some code to implement this solution.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'labels' : ['Hδ', 'Hy', 'HB' , 'OII', ''  , ''  , 'Ha', ''],
    'x'      : [4100, 4400,  4900, 4950 , 5050, 5800, 6700, 6750],
    'y'      : [180 , 300 ,  500 , 800  , 1000, 100 , 1000, 100]
})


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7))
ax.vlines(
    x = df.x,
    ymin = [0] * len(df), ymax = df.y,
    linewidth=2, color='k'
)

for i in range(len(df)):
    ax.text(
        x = df.x[i] - 25, y = df.y[i],
        s = df.labels[i], fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', ha='right'
    )

y_lim = ax.set_ylim(0, 1000)
hide_spines = [ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
x_label = ax.set_xlabel('Wavelength')
y_label = ax.set_ylabel('Flux')
title = ax.set_title('Visible Light Spectrum', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', y = 1.05)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is along the lines of what i had in mind, I am still learning how to use pandas and matplotlib. to add more context to the question here is what the graph should look like. !(https://github.com/martvalencia/RedShift_Analysis/blob/main/Slit28.png) and the csv file i had it formatted as such !(https://github.com/martvalencia/RedShift_Analysis/blob/main/csv_file.png)